# Filling empty fields

Tags: excel, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a very large tab-delimited file (approx 12 million lines) that looks like this:

```
F1    1
      2
      700
F2    89
      900
      10000
      19
F3    100
      60001
```

Is there any way I can make this like:

```
F1    1
F1    2
F1    700
F2    89
F2    900
F2    10000
F2    19
F3    100
F3    60001
```

I've tried using sed scripts but it takes so long.

For example

```
sed 's/^/F1/' FILE | cut -c3- > FILE1 ; mv FILE1 FILE
```

I could do it in excel using

```
=IF(a2=="",c1,a2)
```

and dragging down. However Excel will only allow me to load a certain amount of lines.

(Assuming I've copied "F1" to C1)

Surely there's an easier way with awk or sed?

Comment: Is in line two number `2` prefixed with one or two tabs?

Comment: if it takes a long time with sed it will probably take a long time with awk as well... I could provide a Python solution, but it would be slow too. Problem is disk I/O in that case.

Comment: Lines without a value in column 1 have two tabs

Comment: Any solution would be great :)

Comment: perhaps post a sample of `cat -A file` output.  It matters if the missing value is null, or space or tab.

Comment: 12 million lines does not a "very large file" make.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no, sed is far slower than awk for anything other than simple substitutions on individual lines because it's just not what it's designed to do. So don't assume that something slow in sed will also be slow in awk.

Comment: @EdMorton duly noted. And this time it refrained my to post an `awk` solution (that you would have had to correct afterwards but still... :)). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest:

```
awk -F '\t' '{OFS=FS; $1==""?$1=b:b=$1}1' file
```

Comment: I've tested it now with awk from Solaris 11. It does not work but it works fine with gawk (GNU) from Solaris 11.

Comment: `\t` is not quoted, and becomes `t` - by the shell - which again becomes: `$1 == t`. `t` is an empty variable. But you relay on `\t` will yield `t` in the given shell.

Comment: There's 2 performance issues in that script - 1) Setting OFS=FS for every line of input is obviously slower than setting it once at startup, and 2) Assigning to $1 forces awk to recompile the record every time that happens. Also, an uparenthesized ternary expressions is less easy to read than one in parens and it'll cause syntax errors in some awks in some situations so just always parenthesize it as there's no negative to doing that.

Answer (score 6):

```
perl -F'\t' -lane'$h = $F[0] ||= $h; print join "\t", @F'
```

---

Assignments are right-associative, so

```
$h = $F[0] ||= $h;
```

is equivalent to

```
$h = ( $F[0] ||= $h );
```

and thus to

```
$F[0] ||= $h;
$h = $F[0];
```

and

```
$F[0] = $h if !$F[0];
$h = $F[0];
```

Comment: That's a clever assignment. If you set `$,="\t"`, you don't have to `join`

Comment: I would use `BEGIN {$,="\t"} $h = ...; print @F`

Comment: Why would I use `BEGIN { $, = "\t"; } print @F;` over `print join "\t", @F;'`?

Comment: `perl -aF'/(\t)/' -lne '$d = $F[0] ||= $d; print @F'`

Answer (score 4):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} 
             {if($1!="") p=$1; else $1=p}1' file

F1      1
F1      2
F1      700
F2      89
F2      900
F2      10000
F2      19
F3      100
F3      60001
```

this is the input file I used

```
$ cat -A file

F1^I1$
^I2$
^I700$
F2^I89$
^I900$
^I10000$
^I19$
F3^I100$
^I60001$
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Perl command would look something like this:

```
perl -F'\t' -ple '$c1 = $F[0] if $F[0]; $F[0] ||= $c1; $_=join"\t",@F' 40982582.tsv > your_output.tsv
```

More readably:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -pl -F\t

$c1 = $F[0] if $F[0]; # save off the first column if we have one.
$F[0] ||= $c1;        # override empty first-columns.
$_ = join "\t", @F;   # set the topic back to the full line for -p to print
```

And then run:

```
perl yourscript.pl input_file.tsv > output_file.tsv
```

(You can also use the "-i" flag to overwrite the file "in place" but that doesn't actually save you any time or disk space during runtime.)

Still, however long your file is, that's how long this will take.

Comment: The question says awk, but has the perl tag, so I figured perl was an acceptable option.  Same thing can be done in awk.

Comment: "-F implicitly sets both -a and -n." in perlrun (using 5.22.2 anyway, this may have changed over the years).

Comment: Yeah, that's quite new. 5.20+

Answer (score 2):

This is `sed` solution:

```
sed -r -n '/\w+\s+\w+/{p; s/^(\w+\s+).*/\1/; h};/^\w/!{G;s/^\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+\s+)/\2\1/;p}' file.dat
F1    1
F1    2
F1    700
F2    89
F2    900
F2    10000
F2    19
F3    100
F3    60001
```

**Time consumption and comparison to other awk solutions**

This is code for testing (bash script)

```
#!/bin/sh

## Input file with data to process
inputfile="bigdata3.txt"

## solutions dir, that contains
## - solution files, and
## - every solution file contains code to evaluate
solutions="solutions/"

file_size_kb=$(du -k "$inputfile" | cut -f1)
echo "Size of input file: $file_size_kb kB"
file_lines_count=$(wc -l $inputfile | sed -r 's/\s*([0-9]+)\s+.*/\1/')
echo "Lines of input file: $file_lines_count"

test_code="time \$code > out.txt"
echo "Test code: '$test_code'"

for solution in $solutions* ; do
    ## output file deletion
    if [ -f out.txt ]; then 
        rm out.txt 
    fi;

    code_content=$(cat $solution)
    code="time $code_content $inputfile > out.txt"
    echo "--------------------------------------------------"
    echo "Solution: $solution"
    echo "Code    : $code"
    res=$(sh -c "cd $PWD; $code")
    echo $res

    ## check correctness of output
    incorrect_lines_count=$(sed -r -n "/^[^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/p" out.txt |  wc -l | sed -r 's/\s*([0-9]+)\s*.*/\1/')
    total_lines=$(wc -l out.txt | sed -r 's/\s*([0-9]+)\s+.*/\1/') 
    if [ $incorrect_lines_count -eq 0 ] && [ $total_lines -eq $file_lines_count ]; then
        echo "TEST PASSED"
    else
        echo "INVALID SOLUTION:"
        echo " - not processed lines: $incorrect_lines_count (spaces at line beginning)"
        echo " - total processed lines: $total_lines (expecting: $file_lines_count)"
    fi
done;
```

and results (for 46kB input file):

```
Size of input file: 46034 kB
Lines of input file: 8658000
Test code: 'time $code > out.txt'
--------------------------------------------------
Solution: solutions/Cyrus_awk
Code    : time awk -F '\t' '{OFS=FS; $1==""?$1=b:b=$1}1' bigdata3.txt > out.txt

real    0m8.072s
user    0m7.644s
sys     0m0.420s

TEST PASSED
--------------------------------------------------
Solution: solutions/Ed_Morton_awk
Code    : time awk '{sub(/^\t/,p"&");p=$1}1' bigdata3.txt > out.txt

real    0m11.887s
user    0m11.434s
sys     0m0.389s

TEST PASSED
--------------------------------------------------
Solution: solutions/Marek_Nowaczyk_sed
Code    : time sed -r -n '/\w+\s+\w+/{p; s/^(\w+\s+).*/\1/; h};/^\w/!{G;s/^\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+\s+)/\2\1/;p}' bigdata3.txt >
out.txt

real    0m30.239s
user    0m29.577s
sys     0m0.545s

TEST PASSED
--------------------------------------------------
Solution: solutions/Tanktalus_perl
Code    : time perl -F'\t' -ple '$c1 = $F[0] if $F[0]; $F[0] ||= $c1; $_=join"\t",@F'  bigdata3.txt > out.txt

real    0m6.992s
user    0m6.692s
sys     0m0.281s

TEST PASSED
--------------------------------------------------
Solution: solutions/ikeagami_perl
Code    : time perl -F'\t' -lane'$h = $F[0] ||= $h; print join "\t", @F' bigdata3.txt > out.txt

real    0m12.977s
user    0m12.463s
sys     0m0.483s

TEST PASSED
--------------------------------------------------
Solution: solutions/karakfa_awk
Code    : time awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {if($1!="") p=$1; else $1=p}1'  bigdata3.txt > out.txt

real    0m7.545s
user    0m6.832s
sys     0m0.498s

TEST PASSED
--------------------------------------------------
Solution: solutions/slitvinov_awk
Code    : time awk 'BEGIN   { FS = OFS = "\t" } NF == 1 { print  pre,       $1 } NF == 2 { print (pre = $1), $2 }' bigda
ta3.txt > out.txt

real    0m8.333s
user    0m7.908s
sys     0m0.404s

INVALID SOLUTION:
 - not processed lines: 5772000 (spaces at line beginning)
 - total processed lines: 8658000 (expecting: 8658000)
```

**Conclusions**

@Tanktalus `perl` solution has the best performance, but `awk` @karakfa and `awk` @Cyrus solutions also doing well.

**Offtopic**

This `sed` solution has best performance on smaller file (from this example, and for 8k file), but is really slow on bigger data.

Comment: Nice job, but you could present the test code you used, and run the test for at least 3 seconds to eliminate startup time influence on timing. See for example [Perl module Benchmark](https://metacpan.org/pod/Benchmark).

Comment: Great! Thanks for the update. Now, next thing could be to check if the timings are stable. For example, if you add another `for` loop around the `for solution in $solutions*` where you take the average over say 10 runs, and check if the timings fluctuate wildely across iterations or seems to be fairly constant.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat pre.awk
BEGIN   { FS = OFS = "\t" }
NF == 1 { print  pre,       $1 }
NF == 2 { print (pre = $1), $2 }
```

Usage:

```
$ awk -f pre.awk file.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{sub(/^\t/,p"&");p=$1}1' file
F1      1
F1      2
F1      700
F2      89
F2      900
F2      10000
F2      19
F3      100
F3      60001
```